# Grub does not see Windows 7 after being fixed

Tags: boot, grub2

After I installed Ubuntu on a separate HDD for someone, I was unable to boot into Windows or the Grub option without entering Grub rescue. And after I tweaked `/etc/default/grub`, I am able to enter into Grub, but Grub will not recognize Windows 7 which is installed on my main drive. How can I get Grub to boot into Windows? Ubuntu and Windows are both on separate drives.

Comment: Did you tried `sudo update-grub` while in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If Grub doesn't recognize Ubuntu after being repaired, but Ubuntu boots, open a terminal in Ubuntu and run the following command (as @Braiam also suggested):

```
sudo update-grub
```

It will refresh the Grub menu and add any other detected operating systems to the Grub menu and enable you to choose to boot from them on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Or if above one still dosen't work , you can make sure you have the following :-

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

then  `sudo update-grub`

and that will force grub to look for existing OSes as well!`